# Enum with associated value of default type

Tags: swift

is there a way to define enum associated value type set as default for all its cases instead of defining it for every each of them like below ?

```
enum Device {
    case phone(String)
    case watch(String)
    case tablet(String)
}
```

I want to avoid repeating myself with **(String)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation it might be easier to define it like this:

```
enum DeviceType {
    case phone
    case watch
    case tablet
}

struct Device {
    var type: DeviceType
    var name: String
    ... init, etc.
}
```

Then you can handle the type and string independently of each other, because if every single enum case has a string it sounds like maybe the string is not directly related to the enum value.

Comment: that was basically my first approach but wanted to keep additional data directly in enum type. Is that a bad approach ? Why ?

Comment: I think that only makes sense if each enum case needs different data. If the Device data structure always needs eg. a Name string then it is a separate field and using a struct is cleaner because: a) it shows that the type and the name are different pieces of data. b) it is more extensible if in future you need to add more fields, without having to copy them to all of the cases.
It does make sense to have the data in the enum if it varies depending on which case it is, but in the situation you described I think a struct is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with literals, then why not use `rawValues` instead of associated ones:

```
enum DeviceType: String {
    case phone = "iPhone X"
    case watch = "Longines"
    case tablet = "Samsung"
    // Only literals can serve as raw values, so next line won't work:
    // case notebook = NSLocalizedString("Any personal computer", comment: "")
}
```

If you need mutable associated values of the same type, you might find  Dictionaries useful.

```
// Add CaseIterable conformance protocol to obtain DeviceType.allCases
enum DeviceType: String, CaseIterable {
    case phone = "iPhone X"
    case watch = "Longines watch"
    case tablet = "Samsung tablet"
    // Only literals can serve as raw values, so next line won't work:
    // case notebook = NSLocalizedString("Any personal computer", comment: "")

    // if you don't want any other vars involved you can add a method to enum
    func localizedName() -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self.rawValue, comment: "")
    }
}    
// Create your perfect dict for enum (You'll have to manually add strings to translation)
let deviceTypeLocalized = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(DeviceType.allCases, DeviceType.allCases.map{ NSLocalizedString($0.rawValue, comment: "") }))
// use (or even change) "associated" values with the power of dicts
let localizedWatchName = deviceTypeLocalized[.watch]
// this is how you get your "associated" value from enum without any external dictionaries, without looking it up.
let localizedTabletName = DeviceType.tablet.localizedName()
```